# Piaggio Xevo 125 - water pump kit

Tags: water-pump

I am fixing the water pump on a Piaggio Xevo 125.

The kit supplied contains a gasket/seal but I am not sure where it should go. Any ideas?

[image: seal]
[image: waterpump front]
[image: waterpump back]

Comment: Is this like the kit you bought? https://www.racing-planet.co.uk/water-repair-aprilia-gilera-piaggio-vespa-200cc-piece-shaft-p-177149-1.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=google_merchant&utm_campaign=google_products&gclid=EAIaIQobChMImIOU59LIgQMVkdrtCh0mrQV4EAQYBCABEgJwG_D_BwE

Comment: @handyhowie - Similar. All the parts look the same apart from the little rubber gasket, which is all black in mine and has a spring inside.